# How to change textbox size on form?

Tags: form, inputformtextbox

I am creating a sp 2013 form by creating a js script and a html file that lists the items in a table format, some of my input boxes only contain number so it isn't necessary for me to have the long pre-defined textbox.

How do I change the size of the text box so it can appear something like this?
[image]

instead of having long text boxes like this...
[image]

Comment: anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, 
I went into my js file and added this input..

$('input[title="Dblr3 plat"]').width('100')

As far as the width.

Added after you populate the custom layout